# Can I use a text file to load data into a dictionary in python?

Tags: python

Basically I want to store a dictionary in a text file, the reason for this is I want to be able to open the file and edit it even after I finalise the program.

It's a quiz program I'm using to help me learn the dates of certain events in geological history and I want to be able to add more questions without accessing the code.

So I would want a list of questions with their dates next to them that would be imported back to python, basically a file with a bunch of questions like this:

```
"Pangea formed":335000000, #Carboniferous
"Gondwana split into Africa and South America":180000000, #Jurassic
"The Chicxulub crater, buried in Mexico, formed":66043000, #Cretaceous
```

The problem is I don't think python is made to tell the difference from the string and the value when reading a notepad file.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Python is certainly capable of reading & parsing text files.

Comment: Notepad is just a text editor, python can read whatever file you pass into it and parse

Comment: Python certainly can "tell the difference [between] the string and the value" - _if you tell it how to do it_, and what "string" and "value" actually mean. When you read the file, Python'll see it as a bunch of characters, it won't automagically see any more structure.

Comment: I just googled 'notepad file'... guess you mean text file ;-) Anyway, for the described purpose, I'd suggest to have a look at the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) package.

Answer (score 2):

You want to load the content of a dictionary from a file. The file should be human readable/editable. One solution is to keep the file in JSON format.

[JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) is a format that can be used to convert basic objects like dictionaries, lists into text and vice versa.

So let the content of the file be:

```
{
  "Pangea formed":335000000,
  "Gondwana split into Africa and South America":180000000,
  "The Chicxulub crater, buried in Mexico, formed":66043000
}
```

Now the file, even tough is a text file that you can open and edit in Notepad, is in the JSON format. Notice the opening and closing braces. To load the file into a dictionary you can do:

```
import json

with open('file.json') as f: 
    my_dict = json.load(f)
```

Note that I had removed the comments as JSON doesn't support comments. Also, the last key-value pair doesn't end with a comma.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. Take a look at [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html). It works based on textfiles with the .ini extension.